# Using case statement to compare columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to use a `case` statement to compare multiple rows on 2 columns. For example, if row 1 column 1 and row 2 column 1 match but row 1 column 2 and row 2 column 2 don't, then xx. I have

```sql
CASE
  WHEN (pprof.description = pprof.description and PCtrl.[sequence] <> PCtrl.[sequence])
  THEN xx
```

but that doesn't return any values, which I know to be incorrect. I'm new to SQL so apologies if I've got this all wrong.

Edit:

Here's some sample data:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | -A | -No |
| 123 | -B | -Yes |

Can't figure out the formatting here but there are 3 columns of data above. I'd like the case statement to evaluate whether column 1 match in 2 different rows (i.e., 123 = 123) and also whether column 2 doesn't (A <> B) and if both those conditions are true, return a value in column 3 (in my case, make the No a Yes, since 123-B is Yes). It might be worth noting that the "Yes" and "No" themselves are built into the larger case statement here:

```
(CASE WHEN tenure.description not in ('casual','co-op','fswep') THEN CASE WHEN (pprof.description = pprof.description and PCtrl.[sequence] <> PCtrl.[sequence])
     THEN CASE WHEN (PEmp.Employee_Number = PEmp3.Supervisor_Number) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END END END) as 'People Manager'
```

Comment: What is your table structure, what have you tried?  You may have minor issue if you post this we can help.

Comment: FYI, it's a `CASE` expression. As for the `CASE` expression itself, it doesn't really make sense. `pprof.description = pprof.description` is **always** going to be `TRUE`, unless `pprof.description` has the value `NULL` (as a value always equals itself), and `PCtrl.[sequence] <> PCtrl.[sequence]` will *never* be `TRUE`, as a value can *never* not be equal to itself.

Comment: Consumable sample data (**not** images) and expected results will likely help us help you here.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to do a self join here. Without seeing your data, I can't really give you an answer, but you want something like this.

```
Update A
Set column_3 = 'YES' /* or put CASE statement here /*
FROM pprof A
INNER JOIN pprof B
ON a.description = b.description 
AND a.sequence != b.sequence
```

You may need more join conditions depending on the form of your data and what you want.

Comment: There are other conditions to meet too that are in the case statement. Not just that it should be "yes" of column 1 match and 2 don't.

Comment: So you will adjust the SET line to include the CASE statement as per your needs.